# Limit File Upload Size on client side GWT only

Tags: gwt, gxt

Is there any provision in which i can limit my file upload to some limt ?

I'm using FileUploadField in my GWT screen.

Is there any way i can apply some check that only allows me to upload file max. upto 10MB only ?

TIA !

Answer (score 1):

That is the job of the server. Javascript (and thus abstractions of Javascript such as GWT) are not allowed access to the file being uploaded. The server side should check the file side and throw an exception.

According to http://www.artofsolving.com/node/50 finding the error client side is tricky. You have to actually parse the html results in the iframe used for the upload in the onSubmitComplete event.

Comment: On front End GWT FileUploadField  sends the file through a form submit to a servlet via camel.

If i'll put a check on server side..i dont know how to get it back on the Front End and display it.

Answer (score 1):

As the above answer stated It is not able to be done due to security. It is possible via ActiveX but I am in no way recommending that.

So you can not have a way to check it front end but you could make it seem like it.

Your servlet in this instance would use a push technology such as [Comet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/) to send the status of that file such as too big or completed back to the UI.